# Java Web Application - Creating word document with Apache POI throws error 502

Tags: java, iis, apache-poi

I am currently developing a CGI web-application in java and hosting it on a IIS10-Webserver. The problem I have is the following: If I create a Word-Document using Apache POI and running the application locally on my computer I have no problem creating the file. But when I try to host the application on my webserver, I get a server error 502. I have already found out that I get the error when creating the file. I think this is because the application uses the standard-output to create it. So the problem is I don't have a response-header in that case and I also do not want to have one.

```
public void writeReport(String[] params) {
    try {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename";                
        MysqlDataSource dataSource = null;

        dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();
        dataSource.setUser("user");
        dataSource.setPassword("password");
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setDatabaseName("databasename");

        this.connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        this.statement = this.connection.createStatement();

        this.resultSet = this.statement.executeQuery("select prename, lastname from users where username='"+params[1]+"'");

        String name = "";
        if(this.resultSet.next()) {
            name+=this.resultSet.getString("prename")+" "+this.resultSet.getString("lastname");
        }

        //Blank Document
        XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument(); //Here I get the Server Error 502

        //Headline
        XWPFParagraph headline = document.createParagraph();
        headline.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
        //Ausgeben
        XWPFRun headlineRun=headline.createRun();
        headlineRun=headline.createRun();
        headlineRun.setBold(true);
        headlineRun.setFontSize(20);
        headlineRun.setText("Ausgabezettel");
        headlineRun.addBreak();

        //datetime
        GregorianCalendar now = new GregorianCalendar();
        DateFormat dfDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);
        DateFormat dfTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);

        //Informationen
        XWPFParagraph information = document.createParagraph();
        //Ausgeben
        XWPFRun informationRun=information.createRun();
        informationRun=information.createRun();
        informationRun.setText("Ausgegeben durch: "+name);
        informationRun.addBreak();
        informationRun.setText("Datum: "+dfDate.format(now.getTime()));
        informationRun.addBreak();
        informationRun.setText("Uhrzeit: "+dfTime.format(now.getTime()));
        informationRun.addBreak();


        //create table
        XWPFTable table = document.createTable();       
        CTTblWidth width = table.getCTTbl().addNewTblPr().addNewTblW();
        width.setType(STTblWidth.DXA);
        width.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(9426));

        //create first row
        XWPFTableRow tableRowOne = table.getRow(0);
        tableRowOne.getCell(0).setText("Hersteller");
        tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("Menge");
        tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("Einheit");
        tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("Artikelnummer");
        tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("Lagerplatz");

        //Leerzeilen
        XWPFParagraph emptyLines = document.createParagraph();
        //Ausgeben
        XWPFRun emptyLinesRun=emptyLines.createRun();
        emptyLinesRun=emptyLines.createRun();
        emptyLinesRun.addBreak();
        emptyLinesRun.addBreak();
        emptyLinesRun.addBreak();
        emptyLinesRun.addBreak();


        //Unterschrift
        XWPFParagraph signature = document.createParagraph();
        signature.setBorderTop(Borders.SINGLE);
        signature.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
        //Ausgeben
        XWPFRun signatureRun=signature.createRun();
        signatureRun=signature.createRun();
        signatureRun.setText("Name                                                                       Datum                                                                       Unterschrift");

        // create footer
        XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy headerFooterPolicy = document.getHeaderFooterPolicy();
        if (headerFooterPolicy == null) headerFooterPolicy = document.createHeaderFooterPolicy();
        XWPFFooter footer = headerFooterPolicy.createFooter(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT);

        XWPFParagraph footerParagraph = footer.createParagraph();
        footerParagraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.RIGHT);

        XWPFRun footerRun = footerParagraph.createRun();  
        footerRun.setText("Seite ");
        footerParagraph.getCTP().addNewFldSimple().setInstr("PAGE \\* MERGEFORMAT");
        footerRun = footerParagraph.createRun();  
        footerRun.setText(" von ");
        footerParagraph.getCTP().addNewFldSimple().setInstr("NUMPAGES \\* MERGEFORMAT");

        //Write the Document in file system
        String fileName = dfDate.format(now.getTime())+dfTime.format(now.getTime());
        fileName = fileName.replace(".", "");
        fileName = fileName.replace(":", "");
        fileName = fileName.replace(" ", "");
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName+".docx"));

        document.write(out);
        out.close();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        this.view.returnAnswer("Fehler bei Erstellung des Reports!");
    }
}
```

If anybody knows how to solve or bypass this problem then please tell me. Any help is appreciated. And sorry for my bad english ;)

EDIT:
The application is called with an ajax-request from a javasript which is also on the webserver (c:\inetpub\wwwroot). The application is a .jar file which is handled with a CgiModule.

Comment: print out the exception

Comment: As I have already mentioned, this code works perfectly fine locally, I just get a server error 502 when I host the application on IIS.

Comment: If really `XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument();` causes the problem, then it must be a memory problem since this does not uses resources outside the `RAM`. But why do you thinking that this causes the problem? I suspect `FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName+".docx"));` causes the probem since `filename` is only a name without any directory path and so `document.write(out);` tries to write out somewhere where it has no write access.

Comment: I have put some outputs behind each statement and the first one behind <XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument();> hasn't been printed out, but the output before this statement has. I also commented the FileOutputStream out and I still got the server error 502.

Comment: If you are able to have "some outputs behind each statement", then at first you should check whether a `Exception` is thrown `... } catch(Exception ex) { yourprint ex.getStackTrace().toString(); ...` where `yourprint` is your method to output a string. Because if `new XWPFDocument()` really fails, then  it *should* throw an `Exception`.

Comment: That's the problem. If the programm runs locally it works and I can throw exceptions. But if I host the programm on IIS i can only return the exception if it is thrown before XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(); . Everything else returned after this statement wont work because I get a server error 502.

Comment: "The application is a .jar file which is handled with a CgiModule." How? By running `java -jar jar-file`? If so, what about the class path? Sure, the `apache poi` classes are in the class path?